# VMware Workstation unstable

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have `vFTD VM` running on `VMware Workstation 9.0.4`. When I run `VM` with 3 network adapters, it is stable and = working fine without any issue.
I need to use `4 Network adapters` when I add fourth network adapter in my VM, it reboots continuously and it become `unstable`.
I already `Removed ghost network adapters` and change Network Adapter type to `VMXNET3`, but it does not give any improvement.
It shows message like below:

```
Begin to dump crashinfo to flash ..........
Tracrback output aborted
Flushing First exeception frame:
Process shutdown Finished.
```

**Message**

[image]

Comment: What guest OS do you have, what host ?

Comment: Hi Neil my host pc using Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and Guest OS is cisco firepower threat defense virtual appliance(Linux Based).